# Avoid Drop folder in SMTP settings IIS7

Tags: iis-7, smtp, g-suite

I have a Domain, let's say it's `example.com`

I have an IIS7 server, `example.com` is pointing to that IP and the Reverse DNS is also set to `example.com`.

The e-mail service for this domain is handled by [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business). No e-mail handling were done through my own server.

But the server has some applications where it would need to send e-mails.

At first I was using Google's SMTP and it was fine for tests and small scale stuff, but it had a limitation of sending ~50 e-mails per day and it was barely enough, even for testing.

Then I set up an SMTP on my own server. This needed a whole bunch of configuration, and it seems to be working fine now.

BUT

Since the default domain of my SMTP is `example.com`, every time I send a mail to any example.com address it lands in the Drop folder. Since nothing will ever query that Drop folder, as anything e-mail related is handled by Google Apps, the e-mails will never arrive.

I'm a little afraid to mess with the domain settings, as e-mail servers tend to block e-mails entirely where the domain of the SMTP seems forged (that is why they do a reverse dns lookup).

Is there a way to ignore the fact that the e-mail is sent to the same domain as the default domain on my SMTP server, and send the e-mail anyway?

Should I set my default domain under the SMTP domains to something different to "trick the system"?

I'm not an expert on the subject and I don't want to mess up the SMTP functionality so let me ask:

What would be the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end was setting up the SMTP server on the domain `smtp.example.com`.

Everybody else seems to be setting up their SMTP server on a dedicated subdomain anyway, so it [must be good practice](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hRZDFhn0XA).